# Coerce optBlock in AlgDesign R package to only show certain treatments per row of blocks

Tags: r, algorithm, optimization

Using the `optBlock` function of the `AlgDesing` R package,  I can create a block design with 16 treatments, 12 blocks (columns), and 4 treatment per block (rows) with the following code:

```
optBlock(~.,withinData=factor(1:16),blocksizes=rep(4,12))
```

Which produces the following output:

[image]

My question is how can I coerce `optBlock` to force only certain values to be allowed **WITHIN EACH ROW**? For example, row 1 could only use values 1:4, row 2 could only use values 5:9, and so on to create, as an example, the below matrix:

[image]

Using the blow code I can coerce each block to only use certain values.

```
within<-expand.grid(A=c(1,2,3,4),B=c(5,6,7,8,9),C=c(10,11,12,13),D=c(14, 15,16))
optBlock(~.,withinData=within,blocksizes=rep(4,12))
```

Is there something similar I can do but for the rows?